# Unable to install Hake via cabal install

Tags: haskell, cabal, hake

I'm trying to install hake via cabal install.

Firstly - although the lastest package available is 1.3.7, cabal tries to install 1.2

Apart from that:

```
~ % cabal install hake-1.2
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring hake-1.2...
Building hake-1.2...
Preprocessing library hake-1.2...

Development/Hake.hs:49:8:
    Could not find module `System.Directory.Tools'
    Perhaps you meant System.Directory (from directory-1.1.0.2)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed to install hake-1.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hake-1.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

If I try to be more specific - I get other errors

```
~ % cabal install hake-1.3.7
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: hake-1.3.7
rejecting: base-3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires installed
instance)
rejecting: base-4.5.1.0/installed-81d... (conflict: hake => base<=4.3.1.0)
rejecting: base-4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0,
4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0 (global constraint
requires installed instance)
```

I'm stumped.

*Update*

It seems the author has made the relevant changes to the package in source, at least on GitHub https://github.com/YoshikuniJujo/hake_haskell, but they are not in Hackage yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an upper bound for `base` on `hake` that prevents the latest version from installing with recent versions of ghc. (An older version of `hake` lacks an upper bound but would actually need one, that explains the first error you get.)

The best option is to contact the author and to ask him to upload an updated version to Hackage. The next best (and more immediate) option is to edit the `.cabal` file yourself.

Say

```
$ cabal unpack hake-1.3.7
$ cd hake-1.3.7
```

Then edit `hake.cabal`, find the `Build-Depends:` line which contains `base<=4.3.1.0` and change that to say simply `base` instead. Then say

```
$ cabal install
```

in that directory. Of course, this kind of modifying dependencies isn't always guaranteed to work, but in this case, it seems to.

Comment: Thanks for that - I suppose I should put learning cabal higher up the list.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the dependency `base (≤4.3.1.0)`, `hake-1.3.7` requires a fairly old version of the `base` library.  Looks like it wants [at most GHC 7.0](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/release-7-0-1.html).  Cabal sees that it can't satisfy the requirement for `base`, so it refuses to install `hake`.

`hake-1.2`, on the other hand, does not specify the upper requirement on `base`.  Since Cabal doesn't know about the requirement, it incorrectly tries to build `hake`, and it just fails to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for using my program.
I'm hake author.
I have uploaded new version of hake.
Please try it.
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hake-1.3.8.1